# C# Application.Restart() starts the program twice

Tags: c#

I ran into a weird bug. I called the method `Application.Restart();` which suppose that it will restart the program once. However when I called it, it restarts and start the program not once but twice, resulting two forms on the window. Why is this happening? Please help!

Here is my code:

```
Main.cs

 private void Login_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     // DO some checkings here to see if setting is needed

     if (SettingIsNeeded)
     {
          SettingsForm Settings = new SettingsForm();
          Settings.Show();
     }
 }

SettingsForm.cs

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Settings.Default.COM != comboBox1.Text || Settings.Default.Gate_IP != textBox1.Text || Settings.Default.Server_Address != textBox2.Text) //Check if change has been made
        {
            Settings.Default.COM = comboBox1.Text;
            Settings.Default.Gate_IP = textBox1.Text;
            Settings.Default.Server_Address = textBox2.Text;
            Settings.Default.Save();
            settingschanged = true;
            this.Close();
        }
        settingschanged = false;
        this.Close();
    }

    private void COM_Settings_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (settingschanged)
        {
            Application.Restart(); //This is where only the method will be called for restart.
        }
    }
```

Comment: maybe you call it twice. can we see your code?

Comment: Need to post relevant code too, right click on a application.restart and go find all references then post thosemethods if relevant

Comment: Or the original instance is blocking attempts to shut it down

Comment: It may because your not disposing your form correctly, use using

Comment: @Sayse, can you be provide some examples? thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm just guessing here, but what happens if you try this?

```
private bool isRestarted;

private void COM_Settings_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    if (settingschanged && !isRestarted)
    {
        isRestarted = true;
        Application.Restart(); //This is where only the method will be called for restart.
    }
}
```

Comment: @Matthew - like Default, I also went to do some research and came to the same conclusion, instead of using a new boolean value you can do
 `settingsChanged && e.CloseReason != CloseReason.ApplicationExitCall`

Answer (score 1):

add a `return;` after the first `this.Close();`.

*Probably* calling Close() twice also triggers the FormClosing handler twice? (just a guess)

**Update**

The correct way to use `Application.Restart()` is to call it from Program.Main() as illustrated in [this CodeProject article](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/484290/Application-Restart-Does-Not-Work-Properly).

Comment: Thanks - this codeproject example was a solution for me

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to add some findings here. You could do it like [Matthew](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16881097/238902) has suggested, but I do think there are some issues with your code.
My two cents would be to *not* call `Restart` in `FormClosing` but rather only trigger a `Start` (with  for instance `Process.Start`)

Why did you get two Application starts?
It seems to be because `Application.Restart()` also triggers the `FormClosing` event. The stacktrace for calling `Application.Restart()` is:

```
new StackTrace();
{   at WindowsFormsApplication1.Form1.Form1_FormClosing(Object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.OnFormClosing(FormClosingEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.RaiseFormClosingOnAppExit()
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ExitInternal()
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.Restart()
   at WindowsFormsApplication1.Form1.button1_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
```

while the stacktrace for `Close()` is

```
new StackTrace();
{   at WindowsFormsApplication1.Form1.Form1_FormClosing(Object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.OnFormClosing(FormClosingEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.WmClose(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.WndProc(Message& m)
```

So you do get the `FormClosing` event twice, which will trigger `Restart` twice, meaning two `Starts` and two `Exits`. But since there is only one program to exit, I guess that one of them are ignored (instead of for instance throwing an exception).

As an example, you'd enter `FormClosing` twice if you'd call `Close()` in `FormClosing` as well.

```
new StackTrace();
{   at WindowsFormsApplication1.Form1.Form1_FormClosing(Object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.OnFormClosing(FormClosingEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.WmClose(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
   at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.SendMessage(HandleRef hWnd, Int32 msg, Int32 wParam, Int32 lParam)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.SendMessage(Int32 msg, Int32 wparam, Int32 lparam)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.Close()
   at WindowsFormsApplication1.Form1.Form1_FormClosing(Object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
```